# Python: How to Multi-Thread a Function that Returns Multiple Values

Tags: python

[removed by author, closing account]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to modify your function a little bit to use **[`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)** for getting results.

```
import threading, Queue

def func1(queue):
    x = 2
    y = 5
    queue.put((x, y))

queue = Queue.Queue()
new_thread = threading.Thread(target=func1, args=(queue, ))
new_thread.start()
new_thread.join()

x, y = queue.get()
```

Comment: Spent the last 6 hours trying to figure this out. Thank you kind stranger