# How to multi thread an a function that returns data from an API call

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to request data from various APIs. The servers must be called at the same time, I know I need to use multi threading but I can't figure out how to return the data in the way I want, here's an example.

```
import requests
import time
import threading

t = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
def getBitstamp():
    data = requests.get('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/')
    data = data.json()
    ask  = round(float(data['ask']),2)
    bid  = round(float(data['bid']),2)
    print 'bitstamp', time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    return ask, bid

def getBitfinex():
    data = requests.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd')
    data = data.json()
    ask  = round(float(data['ask']),2)
    bid  = round(float(data['bid']),2)
    print 'finex', time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    return ask, bid 

while True: 
    bitstampBid, bitstampAsk rate = thread.start_new_thread(getBitstamp)
    bitfinexAsk, bitfinexBid = thread.start_new_thread(getBitfinex)
    #code to save data to a csv
    time.sleep(1)
```

It seems however the thread doesn't like return multiple (or even any values) I think I have misunderstood how the library works.

EDIT removed error `rate` variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide if you want to use high-level `Threading` module or low level `thread`. 
If later then use `import thread` and not `import threading`

Next, You also need to pass a tuple with the argument to run the function within `thread`. If you have none, you can pass an empty tuple as below.

```
bitstampBid, bitstampAsk, rate = thread.start_new_thread(getBitstamp,())
bitfinexAsk, bitfinexBid = thread.start_new_thread(getBitfinex,())
```

The program now executes, how-ever runs into separate errors which you may want to debug.
Here are couple of error I noticed.
getBitstamp() returns `rate`, however, `rate` is not defined within getBitstamp(). Program errors on this.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\amPython\multiThreading1.py", line 28, in <module>
    bitstampBid, bitstampAsk = thread.start_new_thread(getBitstamp,())
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> bitstamp 03/18/2017 00:41:33
```

Some ideas on multi-threading are discussed [on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535401/simple-way-to-run-multiple-python-threads) that may be useful for you.

Comment: sorry `rate` wasn't meant to be in there. The post you linked to didn't help either

Comment: I solved it with this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711357/python-how-to-multi-thread-a-function-that-returns-multiple-values Haha also notice that it was coincidently me who made that post you linked to 1 year ago